# how to display chinese character in BASH shell

Tags: centos, character-encoding

I need to launch a binary in bash and the output of the binary consist of some Chinese character. so my question is how to let bash display Chinese character correctly. by the way,
I use Centos.

Comment: You may need to know what character set and encoding (Big5, UTF8, ...) the binary uses. It should pick this up from the CentOS environment variables (e.g. LANG) but may have it's own settings. You also need a font that contains the character set (Simplified, Traditional, ...) and configure the display (terminal app, console or X-Windows) to use it.

Comment: And use correct font, of course. I use YaHei Consola/YaHei Mono.

Answer (score 5):

You need UTF-8 encoding to have all Chinese characters displayed correctly.

To see your current locale just type
`locale` and you will get a similar output like this:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

If you see a `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` or similar including the "UTF-8" substring, you will have all Chinese characters shown correctly.

Also, keep in mind that your terminal needs UTF-8 support too. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25235/centos-locale-utf-8) could give further information.

Comment: I think you need set "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" too to make it works.At least it's the only way that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change TWO files, you need to add `.UTf-8` to the end of `LANG=` and `LANGUAGE=`:

1) In `/etc/default/locale`

```
LANG=" en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE=" en_US:en.UTF-8"
```

2) In `~/.pam_environment`

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

3) reboot

Answer (score 0):

As centos7/8 are widely used,  it is convinient to just install a group of rpms to display non ascii characters.

```
yum groupinstall -y Fonts
```